# Usar res.redirect node.js dentro de una función de mosquitto

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, ejs

estoy usando mosquitto para recibir mensajes de diagnostico y cuando cumpla una condición se redirija a otra url (estoy usando node.js)
El problema esta en que me da este error

> throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');

```
function mensaje(topic,message){
  if(message=='listo'){
    if(c==lista_filtrada.length){
      res.redirect('/inicio')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `res` por lo general es una representacion de la respuesta en un middleware del lado del servidor, si el mensaje de diagnostico lo estas recibiendo en el servidor y no depende de un cliente en particular es medio dificil saber a que cliente redireccionar. si el mensaje lo recibis en el cliente con un location.replace bastaría. podrías dar un poco mas de contexto para ver si es "resolutible"? ( incluir la definición de res por ej. )

Comment: No me deja poner todo el código de res por que es muy largo pero literal todo el res es la función de mqtt: `function mensaje(topic,message){` y dentro de ella hay condicionales que evalúan los posibles mensajes, lo que yo quiero es intentar salirme de la res y pero lo que sospecho que es el problema es que la función de mqtt esta generando problemas al "salirse" tan forzado (aun habiendo hecho el client.end(), al parecer genera un problema si intento hacer cualquier movimiento de res dentro de la función de mqtt